# Module_Error_Not_Found_in_Khernel

Tags: python, statistics

I was in my Python Khernel, the virtual Khernel to be precise, and then I ran the below code

`from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport`

However, I kept on getting the error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[10\], line 1
\----\> 1 from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ydata_profiling
```

Please How do I go about fixing this?

I have tried installiing the package for `ydata_profiling` but it is still not working.

Code I used `conda install ydata_profiling`

The error message

```
(nativenerd) imac@IMACs-iMac ~ % conda install ydata_profiling 
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: osx-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - ydata_profiling

Current channels:

  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I expected to get the package installed and `Solving environment: Success`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because the package is not available from the default channel. To fix this, you need to add the conda-forge channel to your conda configuration and set the channel priority to strict. This will ensure that conda will look for the package in the conda-forge channel first. Write down these commands in Terminal:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

Then you can try to install ydata_profiling again with:

```
conda install ydata_profiling
```

Although, I personally use pip for installing the desired packages:

```
pip install ydata_profiling
```